# Switching between branches causes changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, git-checkout

When I switch between branches, it causes changes on the branch that I switch to, and the changes is always to random files. When looking at the changes, there is nothing different but it is insisting that something has changed. When I undo changes, it doesn't do anything. The only thing I can do to proceed is to commit those files, then continue working.

Also committing png and zip files causes the files to become corrupt on the git repo, so others who sync will get messed up files.

I thought it might be to do with the line-endings, but I'm fairly new to git and not sure how to resolve this random issue. Any ideas?

Here is a git diff of a file that shows changes:

```
diff --git a/Presentation/Emails.vb b/Presentation/Emails.vb
index a767a0d..91e9613 100644
--- a/Presentation/Emails.vb
+++ b/Presentation/Emails.vb
@@ -1,351 +1,351 @@
-<U+FEFF>Imports System.Data
-Imports System.Web
-
....rest of the file
```

I notice it has "U+FEFF" at the start, what does this mean?

Comment: Can you run `git diff <changed-file>` and add the output?

Comment: `U+FEFF` is the byte-order marker (BOM), nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Since you tagged this visual-studio-2015: is VS messing up your files? Did you try switching branches while VS is not running?

Comment: @Thomas Yes I'm switching in VS. I have just tried a git checkout outside VS and it has the same issue.

Comment: If it's to do with line endings, `git diff` would show all lines being removed, then added again. Unfortunately `diff` is not smart enough to show this properly.  GitHub has [good documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) on how to deal with line endings.

Comment: I've followed this guide previously, and have setup the gitattributes as recommended, but this has not resolved this issue.

Comment: If BOM is the difference when switch branches, maybe you should check your VS charcode configuration firstly.

Answer (score 0):

> Also committing png and zip files causes the files to become corrupt on the git repo,

Make sure that git config core.autocrlf is set to false.
If not, it will mess up binary files, trying to change "end-of-line" character sequences which are *not* "eol" in said binary.